# jQuery steals click from children

Tags: jquery

Say i have

```
<h3>
  some text
  <a href="google.com">google</a>
</h3>
```

I want to attach a click event to the h3

```
$("h3").click(function(){ $(this).slideDown(); return false; });
```

but I also want to preserve the clicking on the actual link. Is there a way to do this with jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: Your title looks like a news headline...

Comment: poor children :(

Comment: This effect is called event bubbling

Comment: :) jQuery is an a-hole stealing things from children like that

Comment: I voted for this question based on the wording of the title alone! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check the event's actual [`.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) and do nothing if it was an `<a>` element, for example:

```
$("h3").click(function(e){ 
  if(e.target.nodeName == 'A') return;
  $(this).slideDown(); 
  return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Just don't prevent the default behavior:

```
$("h3").click(function(){ $(this).slideDown(); });
```

Also, do you mean `.slideUp()`? How can you click on something before it slides down?

### [Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V2GkM/)

Comment: The actions inside are irrelevant. Mr. Craver nailed the thing :)

Comment: @Silviu - This method works too, and it's more concise if you don't need the `return false;` for some other reason.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to click on the <a> and have the <h3> event triggered. My bad for not giving enough details. Still upvoted you, as your answer is correct.

Comment: @Silviu - I see. Yes, in that case you have to use Nick's method.